# Transform chained layers in Gimp like one same merged layer

Tags: gimp, transform

How I can transform (Scale, Rotate..) chained layers in Gimp 2.10 simultaneously? For example, I set chain icon to 2 or more layers and want scale them like one merged layer.

Answer (score 3):

That's the purpose of the chained items. Caveat: the transform tool (scale/rotate/etc...) only previews the active one, the others are scaled/rotated when you commit the transform.

Possible trick:

1. Create a layer with everything using `Layer>New from visible`
2. Chain that layer and the other layers
3. Apply the transform to the new layer, and commit when it looks good.
4. Delete that new layer, the other layers should have been transformed too.

Comment: Is any solution to view result before commit?

Comment: Possible trick for this in edited answer.

Comment: Good answer.  Important step when doing this -- according to @xenoid at https://superuser.com/questions/1212791/re-apply-transformation-to-another-layer-gimp -- make sure you don't have a "selection" active when doing this, or certain transforms may not be applied to linked layers.  Just hit "Select: None" before doing the transform.